# How to hide a tag based on the value in ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view called like:

```
@Html.Partial("PersonSearch", new ViewDataDictionary { { "searchtypeselectvisible", false } })
```

In the razor file I have the html:

```
<div class="searchtypeselect" >
        <input type="radio" name="searchtype" value="person" checked="checked" />Person
        <input type="radio" name="searchtype" value="organisation" class="orgsearchradiobtn" />Organisation
    </div>
```

I know I can access the data in the razor by using:

```
@ViewData["searchtypeselectvisible"]
```

Can someone explain how I can hide the div with class searchtypeselect if the value coming through is false and show it if the value is true?

Comment: you can google this http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_cs_logic.asp

Comment: that's not how I really wanted to do it. I wanted to set the hidden attribute on the tag. I still want the markup to be there I just want it to be hidden

Comment: I imagine you could reason it out. honestly, this is a bad question. You haven't done any research of your own and basically want someone to do your work for you. That's NOT what SO is for.

Comment: I personally like to avoid logic in my views, so I suggest adding a model that you can bind to your div element to set the appropriate setting to show/hide it. You could potentially bind the class attribute to searchtypeselect or another displayNone class

Comment: oh, there is no model for this one. It's a search with no data to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@{ if{ } }` to set attribute style with `display: none`, easy.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional attribute rendering [Conditional attribute rendering](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/02/16/asp-net-4-beta-released.aspx)

If you have an attribute that might be null, in the past you've needed to do a null check to avoid writing out an empty attribute, like this:

```
<div @{if (myClass != null) { <text>class="@myClass"</text> } }>Content</div>
```

Now Razor is able to handle that automatically, so you can just write out the attribute. If it's null, the attribute isn't written:

```
<div class="@myClass">Content</div>
```

So if @myClass is null, the output is just this:

```
<div>Content</div>
```

try like this

```
@(ViewData["searchtypeselectvisible"]==true ? "yourDisplayClass" : "yourHidingDivClass");
```

Comment: [This is also a good explanation link](https://gist.github.com/jonlabelle/8738373#conditional-attributes).